# adding selected strings from first column to another column of a dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to paste some of strings from the first column named `Var1` to the last column named `Var2`

The data looks like this

```
df1<- structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(35L, 34L, 33L, 32L, 31L, 30L, 
29L, 28L, 27L, 26L, 25L, 24L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 20L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 
16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("F117", "F97", "F87", "F79", "F67", "F61", 
"F60", "F58", "F41", "F35", "F31", "F30", "F26", "F25", "F23", 
"F22", "F21", "F19", "F18", "F17", "F16", "F15", "F14", "F13", 
"F12", "F11", "F10", "F9", "F8", "F7", "F6", "F5", "F4", "F3", 
"F2"), class = "factor"), Freq.x = c(252L, 106L, 56L, 32L, 28L, 
17L, 10L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
NA, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA), 
    Freq.y = c(306L, 170L, 69L, 45L, 35L, 20L, 13L, 7L, 12L, 
    3L, 6L, NA, 7L, NA, 1L, 3L, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 
    1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L)), .Names = c("Var1", 
"Freq.x", "Freq.y"), row.names = c(10L, 13L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 
23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 27L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 28L, 
29L, 12L, 30L, 14L, 31L, 15L, 32L, 18L, 20L, 33L, 34L, 22L, 35L, 
25L, 26L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to copy the first string, then each 10 strings and finally the last string 
from the `Var1`to `Var2`

So the output will look like this

```
df2<- structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(12L, 18L, 22L, 24L, 26L, 30L, 
32L, 34L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 23L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 31L, 33L, 
35L, 3L), .Label = c("F10", "F11", "F117", "F12", "F13", "F14", 
"F15", "F16", "F17", "F18", "F19", "F2", "F21", "F22", "F23", 
"F25", "F26", "F3", "F30", "F31", "F35", "F4", "F41", "F5", "F58", 
"F6", "F60", "F61", "F67", "F7", "F79", "F8", "F87", "F9", "F97"
), class = "factor"), Freq.x = c(252L, 106L, 56L, 32L, 28L, 17L, 
10L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 
2L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA), Freq.y = c(306L, 
170L, 69L, 45L, 35L, 20L, 13L, 7L, 12L, 3L, 6L, NA, 7L, NA, 1L, 
3L, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 
NA, 1L, NA, 1L), Var2 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("", 
"F11", "F117", "F2", "F22", "F61"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Var1", 
"Freq.x", "Freq.y", "Var2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(10L, 
13L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
27L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 28L, 29L, 12L, 30L, 14L, 31L, 15L, 32L, 18L, 
20L, 33L, 34L, 22L, 35L, 25L, 26L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[c(seq(1, .N, 9), .N), Var2 := Var1][is.na(Var2), Var2 := ""]
```

---

Or use `.I`

```
setDT(df1)[df1[, .I[c(seq(1, .N, 9), .N)]], Var2 := Var1][is.na(Var2), Var2 := ""][]
```

#### Update

Based on the comments,

```
setDT(df1)[c(1, tail(seq(0, .N, by = 100), -1), .N), Var2 := Var1][is.na(Var2), Var2 := ""][]
```

Comment: there is one problem with it. If the data is more than 100, then the first is correct but after that it changes. try to applying it on a 1000 rows and then paste each 10

Comment: @nik It is not clear what the sequence you want `seq(1, 200, by = 9)#
 [1]   1  10  19  28  37  46  55  64  73  82  91 100 109 118 127 136 145 154 163 172 181 190 199`

Comment: I want 1, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 780 . the second approach also does not work

Comment: @nik But, then your sequence showed in 'df2' is not correct

Comment: it is small data, if I post the biggest data here , it is very difficult . but you can generate a dummy one , no?

Comment: @nik Yes, but now you want the difference in 100s?  Because previously it was within 10's

Comment: Yes, 100, I did it like `setDT(df1)[df1[, .I[c(seq(1, .N, 99), .N)]], Var2 := Var1][is.na(Var2), Var2 := ""][]`  which did not work

Comment: @nik If you want something like that, then `c(1, tail(seq(0, 780, by = 100),-1), 780)`

Comment: I liked and accepted your answer. One more request . is it possible to show me how I paste for example instead F1, Functional1 ? and for the rest in Var2 ?

Comment: @nik You can do `setDT(df1)[c(1, tail(seq(0, .N, by = 100), -1), .N), Var2 := sub("(\\D+)(\\d+)", "\\1unctional\\2", Var1)][is.na(Var2), Var2 := ""][]`

Answer (score 1):

Using base R - logic : use `c(seq(1, nrow(df1), by = 9), nrow(df1))` to select the location you wanted. This returns `1 10 19 28 35`

```
df1$Var2 <- ""
df1$Var2[c(seq(1, nrow(df1), by = 9), nrow(df1))] <- as.character(df1$Var1[c(seq(1, nrow(df1), by = 9), nrow(df1))])
```

---

using the `mod` operator : `c(TRUE, (seq(nrow(df1))%%10==0)[c(-1, -nrow(df1))], TRUE)` : insert TRUE to first and last locations, and for every 10th poisition which you can get from `%%` operator

```
df1$Var2[c(TRUE, (seq(nrow(df1))%%10==0)[c(-1, -nrow(df1))], TRUE)] <-
      as.character(df1$Var1[c(TRUE, (seq(nrow(df1))%%10==0)[c(-1, -nrow(df1))], TRUE)])
```

---

Comment: I liked your answer , Thank you

Comment: nik did i get it right? i got a better logic for sequence actually

Comment: yes it is right, the other problem is when we use larger data, then it fails but I liked your answer because it is brilliant and I learned from it